# Oracle package global variables with multiple sessions

Tags: oracle, session, variables, jdbc, package

I have an Oracle Package with some Global Variables which are initialized and used on all procedures of that package.

When I call the procedures (via jdbc connection and calls) the global variables are correctly initialized and their values persists through all procedures on the database session that was opened, but when I have multiple jdbc connections it seems that the global variables values are mixed between the calls.

Isn't Oracle sessions isolated in terms of packages variables? Is there some configuration that I need to do on the database or user profile to guarantee that isolation?

My DB Instance is in a RAC with 2 nodes.

Comment: Please check the Bug: Bug 9681133 ORA-6508 and/or wrong results on valid package variable in RAC https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=73092831412679&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1348303.1&id=9681133.8&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=6rwbo0st0_105 It might be the issue for you. Btw, if you have already solved this issue, please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each database session has its own set of variables, yes.

I would expect that your Java application is using a connection pool such that your Java application is constantly getting connections from the pool and returning them to the pool.  If that's the case, there is no relationship between a Java session and an Oracle session.  A particular Java session might use Oracle session A for the first call, Oracle session B for the second call, C for the third call, and B again for the fourth call.  And other sessions would be doing the same thing so the state of session B might have changed between the two calls because some other Java session used it in the interim.

Some connection pool implementations explicitly clear out package variables when a session is returned to the pool so that data doesn't leak from one session to another.  Other implementations would allow the different Java sessions to see the package variables in whatever state they happen to be from the prior call.  In either case, maintaining state in packages as part of an enterprise Java application is a bad idea.

It is possible that you want a global context instead but it's hard to know that for sure since we don't know what problem you're trying to solve with your package variables.

Comment: Thanks Justin. To work properly each jdbc session must have their own scope of global variables, I'm getting incorrect behavior and data when the glboal variables are mixed between sessions. The java application that connects to the database is a third party application (Tibco) and it is very likely that connection pooling is enabled. I will try to get in contact with this team and see if they can manage this issue. In time, is ther any other configuration I can do in oracle to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @Lucas - In theory, you could re-architect the Java application to not use connection pooling and to allocate an Oracle session to a Java session for the life of the Java session.  That would drastically increase the number of Oracle sessions you would need that would almost certainly require you to use shared server/ MTS on the database server.  But it seems highly unlikely that you're going to convince the folks that wrote the third-party application to do a very substantial rewrite for you.  Most likely, you're going to need to get away from packages with state.

Comment: @JustinCave so what was the solution for this? I have a similar case here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796032/changes-in-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse]

Comment: @Lucas I tried DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE; but it doesn't clear session and can't figure out how to use DBMS_SESSION.CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT

Comment: @SelimAlawwa - I'm not sure what you're asking.  In the linked question, you're saying that `RESET_PACKAGE` works in Oracle but there is nothing equivalent in MySQL.  `RESET_PACKAGE` resets package variables.  If it is not doing what you expect, create a new question with a reproducible test case.  You'd use `CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT` if you are creating and using application contexts to store state.  Have you created a custom application context?  That would be pretty unusual if you wanted the application to work with multiple databases-- contexts are a very Oracle thing.

Comment: @JustinCave RESET_PACKAGE did not achieve what I need and I do not know how to use CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT, please check my new questions for more details: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851641/oracle-reset-package-does-not-reset-value-of-a-variable-in-the-session]