# Changes in database session context persists with pooled connection reuse

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, multithreading, connection-pooling

In my application I have multithreads that needs to access database and I am using [apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html) as a JDBC connection pool.

In some cases users execute stored procedures that might affect the database session context/variables before executing another query to retrieve some data.

After a thread is finished, connection is closed but the way the pooled connections work, the connection is not actually closed but rather returned to the connection pool for reuse. The problem is similar to this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990609/changes-to-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse).

The problem is that these variables usually affect the data retrieved from the database. So when another thread acquire a connection where these variables/context where set and then query the database the data retrieved is affected by the context/variables.

What is the best way to handle such an issue? I have outlined some solutions but not sure which is best practise and not how to implement them all?

**Execute a Procedure / Statement that reset session / variables before releasing the connection back to the pool:**
This solution could work but the issue is my application use different databases. For now MySQL and Oracle are supported. For Oracle we have [RESET_PACKAGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a89852/dbms_s11.htm) Procedure, but there is no equivalent for MySQL. Is there a way to do it in MySQL? also what if new databases are supported?

**Is there a way to enforce or explicitly close the actual/physical connection instead of just returning it to the pool?** or Is there a property to enforce pool to close the connection?

**Does rollback to a savepoint revert db session variables / context?**

```
Savepoint savepoint = connection.setSavepoint();
// execute some procedure connection that affect session
connection.rollback(savepoint);
connection.close();
```

Or is there any other way to enforce clearing of session or restart/close the actual connection?

My question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990609/changes-to-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: You could write a stored procedure to reset the session variables on MySQL.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes a possible solution is to write a procedure to revert the procedure that changed the session value. But the idea is to have a generic way to do it. i.e a procedure that reset ALL session variables / context. Is there a pre-defined mysql procedure?

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL you might perform the sequence:

```sql
BEGIN;
COMMIT RELEASE;
```

as your `validationQuery`. The `RELEASE` part disconnects the current session and creates a new one (cf. [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)).

Comment: Do you a clean solution for Oracle as-well? please check this too [https://stackoverflow.com/q/65851641/8863925] but I need a generic solution that clear / restart session and all its related variables.

Comment: Since stored procedures caused the problem, you can install on both servers a stored procedure (let's call it `reset_session`), which will contain specific code to reset the session on that server.

Comment: Your solution should restart session in mysql? Is there not a pre-defined procedure that re-initiates or clear all session variables value in oracle or mysql? Since we might not have an option to install on both servers reset_session procedure.

Comment: Yes, it resets the session. The binary protocol used by MySQL provides also a [COM_RESET_CONNECTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.12/page_protocol_com_reset_connection.html) packet, which allows to effectively reset the environment, but there is no way to call it from the JDBC driver.

Comment: So this solution is not valid from a JDBC driver perspective. Do you have another idea that can work and is generic or a pre-defined procedure that either restart session or clear all its variables? 
If you'd implement reset_session in orcale how would you do it?

Comment: Alternatively do you know how can we enforce closing of actual physical connection when using tomcat JDBC pool?

Comment: If you use the other pooling `DataSource` distributed with Tomcat (`tomcat-dbcp`), you can call `connection.unwrap(PoolableConnection).reallyClose()`. I don't know if there is an equivalent with `tomcat-jdbc`.

Comment: ok will check this. But do you have another way to clear session / variables using procedures? or how do u implement  `reset_session`