# Oracle RESET_PACKAGE does not reset value of a variable in the session

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, connection-pooling

I have an app where JDBC connections are pooled. This is related to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796032/changes-in-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse). For simplicity let's assume I have 1 connection and I need to set a variable then reset session / context state. However the idea is not reverse / reset the 'app1_ctx' variable particularly as in the actual case users can enter many procedures that set many variables so what I need is one procedure that clears all session related variables or even restart session. (please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990609/changes-to-database-session-context-persists-with-pooled-connection-reuse?noredirect=1&lq=1) too to understand the problem )

Below is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT app1_ctx USING app1_ctx_package;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE app1_ctx_package IS
  PROCEDURE set_empno (empno NUMBER);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY app1_ctx_package IS
  PROCEDURE set_empno (empno NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('app1_ctx', 'empno', empno);
  END;
END;
```

Then when checking value of 'empno':

```
select SYS_CONTEXT ('app1_ctx', 'empno') employee_num from dual;
```

I get employee_num = null

To set the empno variable we run the following:

```
begin 
APP1_CTX_PACKAGE.SET_EMPNO(11);
end;
```

Then when re-checking value of 'empno', I get employee_num = 11

What we need is to clear all session / package variables after this.

I try to clear session variables using [RESET_PACKAGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a89852/dbms_s11.htm) or the below similar procedures.

```
begin 
DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE;
end;

begin
DBMS_SESSION.modify_package_state(DBMS_SESSION.reinitialize);
end;

begin 
DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.FREE_ALL_RESOURCES); 
end;
```

But then when rechecking the variable it still has the same value.

How can I achieve this?

I am not sure how use [CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#i1009975) procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dbms_session.clear_all_context( 'app1_ctx' );
```

You'd need to pass the same namespace to `clear_all_context` that you passed as the first parameter to `set_context`.

If you don't know all the contexts your application uses but you do know all the schemas it uses

```
for ctx in (select * 
              from dba_context
             where schema in (<<schemas your application uses>>))
loop
  dbms_session.clear_all_context( ctx.namespace );
end loop;
```

In this example, there are no package variables so there would be no need to call `reset_package` or `modify_package_state`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I have edited the question pls check 1st paragraph. What I need is a general procedure that clears all session state or related variables or restart/initiates session. As in the real application use case, users can enter more than 1 procedure that change more than 1 variable and what we need to achieve is have 1 command to run after users finish to reset session state so future use of the pooled connection is not affected by this change in session variable

Comment: @SelimAlawwa - Is there more than one context?  That would be a little unusual for an application.  You could iterate over `dba_context` to see all the contexts that your application has created and then call `clear_all_context` for each one.  You'd almost certainly not want to call `clear_all_context` on every context in `dba_context` though since there are a number in the `SYS` and other admin schemas that you almost certainly don't want to touch.

Comment: Our app uses tomcat jdbc pooling, so connections are re-used between clients. We want to clear session after each client is done with the connection before its available for another client. each client can set 1 or more different variables. (he can type any sql/procedure and execute it). Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/q/63990609/8863925] and [https://stackoverflow.com/q/65796032/8863925] to understand the use case.

Comment: So would like a generic procedure to reset value of any session related variable. or restart session if possible.
If I iterate dba_context can I know which are user defined contexts?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa - I understand you're using a connection pool.  But clients are not, presumably, randomly creating new contexts on the fly just like they're not creating new tables on the fly.  So there are going to be a list of contexts that your application uses.  Most applications use 0.  Of those that use contexts, the vast majority use 1.  `dba_context` includes the schema that owns the context so assuming you know what schemas are associated with your application (normally 1) you can narrow down the list.

Comment: Yes clients are not randomly creating contexts. But lets assume that my application user has 5-10 similar procedures as `set_empno`, our app allows user to enter some SQL to be executed let say user sets 2-3 variables having different contexts, what is the best generic way that after the user is done, the connection session state is reset to initial state? Using `dba_context` can u provide an example of contexts that need to be cleared, what contexts are session related?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa - I updated my answer.  If you have similar procedures in the same package but you still have a single context, you would just need to pass the name of the context once.  If you really mean that you have 5-10 similar packages to `app1_ctx_package` that are associated with 5-10 different contexts, you can iterate through `dba_context` assuming you know what schemas your application uses.  Of course, you could also just make 5-10 calls to `clear_all_context` passing in the various known context names.

Comment: Are we sure the jdbc connection will be operating on 1 schema? Would something like this be okay? `begin
        for ctx in (select * from dba_context where dba_context.schema in (SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') CONTEXT_SCHEMA FROM DUAL))
        loop
          dbms_session.clear_all_context( ctx.namespace );
        end loop;
end;` or is there any risk that will change something not required? Is there any case where `RESET_PACKAGE` will be needed?

Comment: running the `CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT` gives ORA-01031: insufficient privileges, So I have privilege to create but not clear / reset?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa - There is no guarantee that the application will connect as the user that owns the context.  Best practice from a security standpoint would, in fact, to do the opposite and connect as a user that doesn't own any objects.  If an application has some reason to use 10 different contexts, there is a decent chance that it would access multiple schemas.  But presumably since this is an application that you're writing you know what schemas it is actually using (and equivalently what contexts it uses).

Comment: @SelimAlawwa -  It probably makes sense to hard code either the list of schemas that your application uses or hard code the list of contexts that your application uses because neither is likely to change much over time.  If you want to create a new table to store either the list of schemas or the list of contexts and reference that table in your code so that you can just add a row to the table when someone decides that the application should deal with another schema or context, that would be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks so in case just 1 schema, then `CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT` for any namespace in this schema should be any problem right? Also how can I handle `CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT` ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error. I am running it from the same user than ran `APP1_CTX_PACKAGE.SET_EMPNO(11);`
So I can run the procedure that internally calls `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT` but I can not use `CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT` how can this be solved?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa - Yes, if 1 schema owns all the contexts that your application uses, then you'd use that in your query against `dba_context` to get the list of contexts to clear.  Are you getting the permission error querying `dba_context`?  Or running `clear_all_context`?  Are you logged in as the same use that owns `app1_ctx_package`?  Has that user been granted `execute` access on `dbms_session`?

Comment: I have tested it from java JDBC and from DB Visualizer. From both I can run `APP1_CTX_PACKAGE.SET_EMPNO(11);` procedure which internally does this `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('app1_ctx', 'empno', empno);` but when I try `DBMS_SESSION.CLEAR_ALL_CONTEXT('app1_ctx');` I get ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you logged in as the same use that owns `app1_ctx_package`? Has that user been granted execute access on `dbms_session`?

Comment: should be same user yes. how can I verify this. And since I can call `APP1_CTX_PACKAGE.SET_EMPNO(11);` then I have execute access on `dbms_session` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227752/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-selim-alawwa).